# Error appears, when event On Current is triggered

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I reference to subform error occurs. I have 1 main form and 2 subforms on the main one. One of subform has On Current event which trigger code:

```
 Me.Parent![1ChildEquipFilter].Form.RecordSource = StrSQL
```

(it changes second subform's RecordSource)

When the main form is opened the first time, the error message appears
'you entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property form/report'.
But when I click on the debug and then reset, all work properly. What's the matter?

Comment: What's strSQL each time?

Comment: "select app_name, id_app from equipment WHERE app_name LIKE " & StrSqlAllWords 
But It seems, when I refer to the form, it has not yet loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the form, *first* the two subforms are opened, then the main form, and then the two subforms again.

The simple workaround is to eat the error:

```
On Error Resume Next
Me.Parent![1ChildEquipFilter].Form.RecordSource = StrSQL 
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a sequence? Which of the subforms does open firstly?

Comment: Put a code line of `Debug.Print Me.Name` into the OnOpen event of each subform and see.